# Amazon S3 - which of Perl packages to use to access it

Tags: amazon, perl

I've found the following FreeBSD Perl packages to access Amazon S3 API.

Please advise me which of them to use:

- [p5-Net-Amazon](http://www.freshports.org/net/p5-Net-Amazon/) (Net::Amazon)
- [p5-Net-Amazon-AWSSign](http://www.freshports.org/net/p5-Net-Amazon-AWSSign)
- [p5-Net-Amazon-Signature](http://www.freshports.org/net/p5-Net-Amazon-Signature)
- [p5-Net-Amazon-Signature-V4](http://www.freshports.org/net/p5-Net-Amazon-Signature-V4)
- [p5-S3](http://www.freshports.org/net/p5-S3)
- [p5-Net-Amazon-S3](http://www.freshports.org/net/p5-Net-Amazon-S3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it is difficult to answer your questions, because it really depends on your needs. How will you use these modules? What program do you have? Have you looked at these modules' documentation to see if they have the features you need?
I'm not an user of any of these modules, but looking at their documentation, features, dates of release and such, I would suggest to try `Net::Amazon` first.

But there are even more modules on CPAN for your need, such as `AWS::S3` or `Paws::S3`. The Paws framework seems to be the newest framework for Amazon stuff, you should maybe have a look at it.
See [Paws::S3](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws::S3) and [Paws](https://metacpan.org/pod/Paws).

Comment: Our requirements are not known in advance. The current task is to make a backup of Google Storage bucket at Amazon. At any time new tasks may appear.

Comment: For an infinite/undefined list of specifications you have an infinite/undefined list of solutions. `Paws::S3` has a `PutObject` method to store data in your S3 bucket.